# How to turn on and off markdown visualization in google docs

Tags: google-docs, markup

I have a google docs document. The author has used some markdown there.
Now I can see it as

````
# First part
here is the first part code
```
print hello world
```
````

I would like to be able to see this as intended with titles and code sections

Note: the Tool->Settings-> Automatically detect markup is ON

Comment: This question is off-topic in [su].

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell from a brief test,

Google Docs only recognises Markdown as you type it, it doesn't work with pasted text unless I go in and edit it, for example by deleting and re-typing the space after the hash mark.

Google Docs only recognises a subset of the original Markdown and none of the common extensions such as tables. It does not recognise "code" formatting using indentation, nor using code-fencing with either back-ticks ` or tildes ~.